# Where will I find the chatroom for Drones and Model Aircraft?

Tags: support

I am still rather new to SE. So maybe this is obvious to everyone else, but I have not found my way into the Chatroom. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main chat is [Droning on](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106718/droning-on), but we also have a [dedicated chat for the election](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108149/drones-election-2020) at the moment.

You can usually find the links to chat on a site's meta page.  Ours currently looks like this:

[image: Chat room links]

Or you can follow the link on the drop-down menu:

[image: drop down]

Hope to see you there.